# Multicolumn ListBox control

Tags: .net, asp.net, listbox

I'm looking for a *free* ASP.NET 2.0 ListBox control that supports display of items in two columns.  It also needs to support selecting multiple items.

I really prefer not to have to use a monospaced font and mess with formatting my ListBox items into columns.

I also saw suggestions to use other types of controls (such as a DataList) but frankly I'm not confident enough in my ability to get such a control to work as cleanly as a standard ListBox - at least not in the time I have to complete my project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would having multiple selections, why not try with `CheckBoxList` control.
Doesn't it solve both your problem of multiple selections and multiple columns?

Tutorial: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/standard/checkboxlist.aspx

Hope it helps!